# FileDescriptor Class in Java

Tags: java, file-descriptor

According to the Documentation,

> **java.io.FileDescriptor** works for opening a file having a specific name. If there is any content present in that file it will first erase
>   all that content and put “Beginning of Process” as the first line.

My **FILE.txt** file contains content as my name 'Jaimin Modi' only.

Now, below is one sample for the use of **FileDescriptor** class in java:

```
import java.io.*;   
public class NewClass 
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    { 
        // Initializing a FileDescriptor 
        FileDescriptor geek_descriptor = null; 
        FileOutputStream geek_out = null; 

        // HERE I'm writing "GEEKS" in my file 
        byte[] buffer = {71,69,69,75,83}; 
        try{ 
            geek_out = new FileOutputStream("FILE.txt"); 
            // This getFD() method is called before closing the output stream 
            geek_descriptor = geek_out.getFD(); 
            // writes byte to file output stream 
            geek_out.write(buffer); 
            // USe of sync() : to sync data to the source file 
            geek_descriptor.sync(); 
            System.out.print("\nUse of Sync Successful "); 

        } 
        catch(Exception excpt) 
        { 
            // if in case IO error occurs 
            excpt.printStackTrace(); 
        } 
        finally
        { 
            // releases system resources 
            if(geek_out!=null) 
                geek_out.close(); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Am getting below output/content in **FILE.txt** as 'GEEKS'.

So, What I have done next is just **commented** the lines for the use of **FileDescriptor**.
Commented below lines :

```
FileDescriptor geek_descriptor = null; 
geek_descriptor = geek_out.getFD(); 
geek_descriptor.sync();
```

and again changed content in **FILE.txt** as 'Jaimin Modi'.

then just executed. What am getting in **FILE.txt** :

'GEEKS'..!!

Am getting the same result with and without the use of **FileDescriptor**.

So, What is the main use of FileDescriptor here. Confused a little. Please guide.

Comment: Please see these links -> [Example 1](https://www.concretepage.com/java/java-filedescriptor-example-with-fileinputstream-and-fileoutputstream)

[Example 2](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/io/filedescriptor/java-file-descriptor-example/)

Comment: @ialam thanks. It shows the practical use of FileDescriptor.

Comment: Welcome. Happy learning. :)